# Does having a space char in a URI affect performance?

Tags: performance, uri

I know that modern browsers will allow URIs with spaces in them, and I imagine that there's some encoding/decoding going on that might not be there otherwise.

Are there any material performance impacts that can be attributed to having spaces in a URI?

Comment: This feature is designed for the user who types a URI with a space into their browser's address bar. You as a web developer should *not* be doing it, so the performance impact can't possibly be relevant.

Comment: Some content management systems allow you to upload a resource with a space in the file name, and do not appear to encode the resulting URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, browsers convert space to %20 so the server will not notice. In fact, in Firefox if you copy a URL that has spaces from the address bar it will be converted to %20.

Also, I think this is not worth pursuing. It would be really hard to measure the performance impact and it seems to be a really tiny part of the load anyway.

Also, the load would be on the PCs,,, not on your servers.

I (as a programmer writing code or links) would type %20 because it is safer (less likely to fail) and closer to what actually happens.

Comment: I (as a programmer writing code or links) would type `%20` because it's what the [spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) tells me I have to do if I want my URLs to work correctly. The grammar indicates that a space character can never be part of a syntactically valid URL. This isn't a subjective issue of preference.